# React Native IOS StoreKit API (ExternalLinkAccount)

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I have submitted [“reader”](https://developer.apple.com/support/reader-apps/) app to the app store and I have problem regarding to ExternalLinkAccount. After IOS 16 update apple requires to use `open()` method instead of creating custom modal component (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/externallinkaccount). So is there any way to call the `open()` method of the `ExternalLinkAccount` in React Native?

I have added all the required fields in the XCode and I have created the custom modal and it works for IOS 15 and below but now for IOS 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by creating a NativeModule that utilizes the iOS StoreKit Framework

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).